# Aggregating data according to month

Tags: r, merge, aggregate, panel-data, cbind

I have a panel dataset containing data on civil war, with indices "side_a_id" and "year_month". Each observation is an individual 'event' of armed conflict, and variables include details on the actors involved, a unique ID for each individual event, and then for each event, the number of side_a deaths, side_b deaths, and civilian deaths.

[Screenshot of sample dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwG61.png)

I would like to aggregate the data on each **separate** variable on deaths ('deaths_a', 'deaths_b' and 'civilian_deaths') according to which year_month they are in. So taking an example from my dataset below: instead of having 3 separate rows for the interaction between Government of Haiti and Military Faction (dyad_id = 14), I would like one row that contains all the deaths of each party for a specific month. I have tried using the the aggregate() function, which seems to work, until I try to re-merge it with my full dataset.

```
    df <- aggregate(cbind(deaths_a, deaths_b, deaths_civilians) ~ side_a_id + 
                     year_month, panel_data, sum)
    rebel <- full_join(panel_data, df, by = c("side_a_id", "year_month"))
```

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example using `dput` (instead of image) and expected output based on that example

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the problem is _not_ the `aggregate` statement, but rather the `join` ?

Comment: @Lee Tagziria - please could you kindly reproduce a sample of the dataframe which I can copy paste into R for us to help you. What you need here is `gather` , `spread`, `group_by` and `summarise` all from the tidyverse

Comment: I think you can also use sqldf and write a sql querry its pretty simple